# Is there in Unicode a circled ten and eleven which look the same?

Tags: unicode

When comparing the Unicode character 'DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED NUMBER TEN' (U+277F) or 'DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED SANS-SERIF NUMBER TEN' (U+2793) with Unicode Character 'NEGATIVE CIRCLED NUMBER ELEVEN' (U+24EB), the ten doesn't look the same as eleven (see below). The situation is the same for their non-negative counterparts.

What was the reasoning behind this incompatibility? Are there other circled digits which are actually compatible (either eleven which follows the size and style of ten, or a ten which follows the size and style of eleven)?

## ❿ ➓ ⓫ — ⑩ ➉ ⑪

Below, the same characters in a Linux terminal. The circles of the second ten and the eleven are of the same size, but the font is completely different.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative circled numbers 1 through 10 originally derive from the *Zapf Dingbats* font and have been part of Unicode since the very beginning, whereas 11 through 20 were only added in version 3.2 [for compatibility](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/99238-non-kanji2.pdf) with new editions of the Japanese *JIS X0213* standard. This has two consequences:

1. Because the two sets of numbers were encoded at different times and are disjoint, some fonts may only contain one or the other, leaving the rest to fall back to a different font.
2. Because the first ten characters derive from a specific font, even modern fonts that do contain the whole set may decide to draw the two ranges with different styles, 1 through 10 imitating the original *Zapf Dingbats* glyphs and 11 through 20 being more in line with the font’s own design principles, i.e. synchronised to the regular circled numbers like “⑪”.

Despite this, these two ranges canonically form one complete set; there aren’t any other Unicode characters with which they are supposed to harmonise. If you want the entire set to be displayed in one consistent style, you will have to find a font that possesses this quality.

Comment: the same reason ¹²³ may be different from ⁰⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ because the former were available in CP437 and ISO-8859-1 before the Unicode era while the latter were only added later in Unicode